# What are the implications of hash collisions?

Tags: encryption, hash

I understand that having collisions will reduce the work required in a brute force attack on a hash algorithm because there are multiple inputs with identical outputs.

However, what I am not clear about are the other types of attacks that would be assisted by collisions, and how detrimental are they really?  Not all weaknesses discovered in a hash algorithm make the algorithm technically weak.  It might still be infeasible to brute force even with collisions.  So what are the other attacks made easier by collisions?

Also is it not possible to append some kind of additional checksum or digest as an additional part of the final hash to prevent collisions?  For example by adding a couple checksum bytes onto the output which may reduce the probability of collisions producing the same hash output coupled with the checksum?  Maybe even hashing the checksum before appending it so that value is even secure?

o = hash(i) & (hash(checksum(i))

Comment: First, every hash function has collisions (by the pigeonhole principle). Cryptographic hashes are collision-*resistant*, in that it is hard to find collisions (specifically, there is no algorithm better than brute force that will discover them; this is a definition. Hashes that fail this are not cryptographic). Adding additional checksums, etc, is just a different hash function, and that hash function will also have collisions. That said, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. The place you want to discuss this is crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. See crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Mooing Duck does make a good point about collisions in non-cryptographic hashes. When you take this to crypto.se, you should be clear about which kind of hash you mean.

Answer (score 2):

- If you use a hash to distribute load, an attacker can craft inputs to all hash to the same machine, and overload that one machine.
- If you use a hash as an identifier for user data, an attacker can craft files that result in the same hash as a random other user's data, causing that data to be replaced.

There are probably many more, but these two came immediately more.

In the first case, this was resolved by including the process ID in the hash to prevent collisions.  In the second case, an error message was added when a new file would replace an existing file.

Comment: I meant attacks that would make the discovery of the input significantly easier.  Specifically when it comes to cryptography and hashing passwords for use as keys in encryption.

Comment: Sorry did not know there was a specific cryptography section for stackexchange.  good to know!

Comment: Attacks that discover the input aren't collision attacks. They're pre-image attacks, which is a different thing. If you are trying to avoid pre-image attacks, you want to use a cryptographic hash (such as SHA-256). Don't try to invent an ad hoc cryptographic hash on your own. It is much more difficult than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments the question seems to be about password cracking.

The issue of discovering passwords that are hashed is generally done with lists of frequently used passwords, see [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).

The main method of thwarting such attacks is to use a password hashing method to create password verifiers that consumes substantial time, generally around 100ms. Such functions include PBKDF2, Argon2, password_hash, bcrypt, etc.

The chance of finding a collision is so minuscule in SHA2 and above as not to be considered in password cracking, there is no additional advantage.

Additionally attackers generally are not interested in a single password but rather a large percentage of passwords obtained from accessing a user database. Then these credentials are sold on the dark web in bulk. It one user in particular is being attacked that is Spear Phishing and there are generally better methods.

For more information see:

- Infosec [password-cracking-tools](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/10-popular-password-cracking-tools/)
- Arstechnica [How I became a password cracker](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/03/how-i-became-a-password-cracker/3/)
- Advanced Password Recovery [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/)